# missing OSGi jar in eclipse mars with liberty profile

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, websphere-liberty

I'm using eclipse mars 4.5.2 for mac OS X 10.11. I create a simple OSGi bundle project and it is missing osgi.core.jar in its classpath.

> The import org.osgi cannot be resolved

[mac-mars classpath screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGjg3.png)

BUT When I do the same actions in eclipse luna 4.4.2 on windows with websphere classic - osgi.core.jar is on its place.

[windows-luna classpath screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q249.png)

What I need to do, to resolve OSGi dependency?

On mac I have the latest ibm websphere liberty developer tools for mars and liberty javaee7 8.5.5.9 (18.03.2016), may be its a bug?

UPD: my manifest on both bundles:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: IgLoginBundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: IgLoginBundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Activator: activator.Activator
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Export-Package: activator
```

*(I'm new to OSGi and just trying to implement a custom user registry for liberty)*

Comment: The error says you have an `Import-Package` that includes `org.osgi`, but there is no such package, there are only subpackages of `org.osgi`, and you need to explicitly list all subpackages (not JARs).  What does your MANIFEST.MF look like?

Comment: @BrettKail added manifest, the error appears on lines: 
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: @BrettKail https://psv4.vk.me/c615330/u248178802/docs/2f34a37465f4/Snimok_ekrana_2016-04-05_v_16_17_53.png?extra=r5xRBD05-qn4c9y_vwhyARGyDq0kf68TvPsRRo7de-dpylfZoDhoBriiF0JIw_fHJ6KNpolguSIyWLx-Pi_gekt3geLUD3GeavQoaIbU1jNnZbkI8_PphknkrxqAU5Z_iYI5Htidna8aLnE

Comment: That link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @BrettKail http://i.imgur.com/uuMDj9q.png

Comment: What happens if you click the "Add import to bundle manifest" button on that hover?  It appears Eclipse doesn't think the Import-Package in your manifest contains org.osgi.framework.  Perhaps you're editing the wrong file?

Comment: @BrettKail if I click it, it do nothing with manifest file, the osgi.jar and/or osgi.core.jar is missing in bundle project classpath, in win+was classic the osgi.jar IS in classpath (see screenshot 2). The problem is that eclipse or developer tools on mac cant find and/or add osgi.jar to classspath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the latest ibm websphere liberty developer tools for mars and liberty javaee7 8.5.5.9 (18.03.2016)

I think the issue is the version of Liberty you are using.  The EE7 edition does not come with the OSGi feature you needed by default.

Try to install the **Liberty Profile V8.5.5.9 with OSGi Application**.  You should be able to download it via IBM WebSphere Liberty developer tools for Mars from the eclipse server view.

[image]

Comment: OP said they were trying to write a custom user registry, not an OSGi application.

Comment: In order to build a CUR in Liberty, user need to create a bundle and feature (https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/creating-a-custom-user-registry-as-a-liberty-user-feature/).  And this is what OP said "I create a simple OSGi bundle project"

Comment: Yes, an OSGi bundle, not an OSGi application.  Why would OP need to download a Liberty runtime with OSGi application support just to build basic OSGi bundles?

Comment: @Alex, please give the answer a try an let us know if the problem is resolved.  Thanks

Comment: AbelardChow, @BrettKail, It solved the problem of missing jar! thank you! Now the com.ibm.ws.org.osgi.core.4.2.0_1.0.12.jar is in Plud-in dependencies section.

Comment: AbelardChow, @BrettKail wow wow, now I deleted wlp-osgi-8.5.5.9 from mac, and in eclipse set Plug-in Development -> Target Platform -> wlp-8.5.5.9 and osgi.jar linked from /wlp-8.5.5.9/dev/spi/spec/com.ibm.wsspi.org.osgi.core.6.0.0_1.0.12.jar, seems like a bug of devtools